# Get width and height from `xcb_get_geometry_reply()`

Tags: c, xorg, xcb

I'm attempting to retrieve the size of the root window via XCB, so as to create a window that size.

I can use `xcb_get_geometry_reply()` to get the geometry, but how can I convert that to `uint16_t` so that I can pass it to `xcb_create_window()` (as width and height)?

Comment: ...what exactly are you asking? I am very confused by "how can I convert that to an `uint16_t` array". Why do are you trying to get an array and what is your problem with just creating an array? Note that argument 7 and 8 of `xcb_create_window` are `width` and `height`, respectively. No arrays involved.

Comment: I apologize. I've rephrased my question.

Comment: Ah, okay. Now I understand what you meant. Sorry for not understanding earlier and no reason to apologise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this page](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.5/doc/libxcb/tutorial/#wingetinfo):

> Just like we can set various attributes of our windows, we can also ask the X server supply the current values of these attributes. For example, we can check where a window is located on the screen, what is its current size, whether it is mapped or not, etc. The structure that contains some of this information is

```
typedef struct {
    uint8_t      response_type;
    uint8_t      depth;         /* depth of the window */
    uint16_t     sequence;
    uint32_t     length;
    xcb_window_t root;          /* Id of the root window *>
    int16_t      x;             /* X coordinate of the window's location */
    int16_t      y;             /* Y coordinate of the window's location */
    uint16_t     width;         /* Width of the window */
    uint16_t     height;        /* Height of the window */
    uint16_t     border_width;  /* Width of the window's border */
 } xcb_get_geometry_reply_t;
```

Therefore, the width/height simply be accessed with `geomtry->width` and `geomtry->height`